Azure Container Apps: Volume mount fails
I have this error when trying to mount a volume in azure container apps with terraform.
Everything looks configured properly as per the documentation, so I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas what could be wrong?
{"TimeStamp":"2024-08-21 15:41:18 \u002B0000 UTC","Type":"Warning","ContainerAppName":"pyapi","RevisionName":"pyapi--hi0d6li","ReplicaName":"pyapi--hi0d6li-7cc8bbcdc5-rjw5x","Msg":"Container \u0027api\u0027 was terminated with exit code \u0027\u0027 and reason \u0027VolumeMountFailure\u0027. One or more errors occurred. (Shell command exited with non-zero status code. StatusCode = 32 | StdOut =  | StdErr = mount error(13): Permission denied\nRefer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)\n) (Shell command exited with non-zero status code. StatusCode = 32 | StdOut =  | StdErr = mount error(13): Permission denied\nRefer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)\n)","Reason":"ContainerTerminated","EventSource":"ContainerAppController","Count":5}

below the code TF
#api.tf
data "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "pyapi_id" {
  name                = "fkallel-aca-id"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_container_app" "pyapi" {
  name                         = "pyapi"
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.fk-apps-env.id
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  revision_mode                = "Single"
  workload_profile_name        = "Consumption" 

  template {
    container {
      name   = "api"
      image  = "docker.io/nginx:latest"
      cpu    = 0.25
      memory = "0.5Gi"

      volume_mounts {
        name = "nfsv"
        path = "/data"
      }
    }

    volume {
      name         = "nfsv"
      storage_name = "nfs"
      storage_type = "AzureFile"
    }

  }
  ingress {
    allow_insecure_connections = false
    external_enabled           = true
    target_port                = 8080
    transport                  = "auto"

    traffic_weight {
      latest_revision = true
      percentage      = 100
    }
  }
  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.pyapi_id.id]
  }
 
}


Did your user managed assigned Identity has necessary role permissions? @user3620514

no, it doesn't need a role permission at this stage


Azure Container Apps: Volume mount fails using terraform

The main issue is the container is the because permission issue with the NFS volume you're trying to mount in the Azure Container App because of network port.
As per the MSDoc we should provide the access for the container to access the shared files by allowing port 80.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  name                     = "tetshvhkstostorageacct"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  name                 = "nfsvk-share"
  quota                = 50
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "example" {
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  name                = "fkvk-apps-env"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_container_app" "example" {
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.example.id
  name                         = "testsamplevksb"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  revision_mode                = "Single"
  ingress {
    external_enabled = true
    target_port      = 80
    traffic_weight {
      latest_revision = true
      percentage      = 100
    }
  }
  template {
    max_replicas = 1
    container {
      cpu    = 0.5
      image  = "nginx"
      memory = "1Gi"
      name   = "testsamplevksb"
      volume_mounts {
        name = "vkazurefil4olume"
        path = "/var/log/nginx"
      }
    }
    volume {
      name         = "vkazurefil4olume"
      storage_name = "venkatvk"
      storage_type = "AzureFile"
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_container_app_environment.example, azurerm_storage_account.example, azurerm_storage_share.example
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_environment_storage" "example" {
  access_key                   = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  access_mode                  = "ReadWrite"
  account_name                 = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.example.id
  name                         = "venkatvk"
  share_name                   = "nfsvk-share"
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_container_app_environment.example, azurerm_storage_account.example
  ]
}

Deployment:



Refer:
Tutorial: Create an Azure Files volume mount in Azure Container Apps | Microsoft Learn
azurerm_container_app_environment_storage | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry

Thank you for response, in my case i have a private storage account. I found the problem at last, effectively it was a misconfiguration at the private endpoint level. it works as expected now

In the code you missed on sharing the info related to storage account so for the demonstration i tried this hope this help you in trouble shooting your issue @user3620514

yes i forget to mention that in the description. anyway thank you for your help
